# Unable To Preview Tables in Database in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have successfully configured a AzureSQL Database link Service but unable to Preview the data/table without specifying the schema in one of my Azure Data Factory instance.

Image without Schema:
[image]

Image with schema added
[image]

However, in my other Azure Data Factory I use for testing I am able to Preview the data/table without inserting the schema, see below

[image]

This is so strange, that I can Preview the data/table without inserting the schema in one Data Factory instance, but I can't Preview the data/table in another instance - I believe I have created the link the exact same way.

Any thoughts?

I should mention the error message that I'm getting when I click for more information is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I have been doing to research. I think the problem is ADF can't handle certain schemas. It doesn't appear to have a problem with dbo. schema.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario in my environment and while researching that I got to know when you don't specify the schema for the table it by default takes **`dbo`** and I am able to preview the table.

[image]

If you created any other schema and you are creating table with that schema you need to specify the schema name in dataset otherwise you will get an error

[image]

please check in both ADF instance linked service you are using same SQL server to connect and if it's different please check that table is under default schema that is **dbo**.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks for getting in touch. So do you know what can be done when you are trying to copy tables that have more than one schema? For example, we have the following schemas, "core.", "enr.", "outbound." as well as the default schema "dbo."?